# java.io.IOException: write failed: ENODEV while writting data to arduino from JellyBean device

Tags: android, usb, arduino, adk

Am getting

```
E/xx( 5508): java.io.IOException: write failed: ENODEV (No such device)
E/xxx( 5508):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:462)
E/xxx( 5508):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:187)
E/xxx( 5508):   at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
```

when writing(via USB) data to Arduino from my jelly bean device.
Code in Android for writing is

```
try {
           String buff = new String(v.getText().toString());
           buff += '\0';
           mOutputStream.write(buff.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) {
           Log.e(TAG, "write failed", e);
}
```

and code for reading in arduino is

```
  while (Serial.available()) {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read(); 
    inputStringFromSerial += inChar;
    if (inChar == 0xd) { // inchar == '\n'
      stringComplete = true;
    } 
  }
```

Even though my Android can detect the accessory automatically and start my app automatically I cannot write to or read from Arduino. Permission is also acquired properly

Also from where do I get latest ADK libraries for Arduino?Some libraris need acc.powerOn() while some need acc.begin() to start.Which one is latest?

I got it working for just once without any code changes.But only once, after that no :(

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the device is no longer connected. I suspect some code in other part of your app or another app, which is also trying to connect to the same accessory.

If you are using Arduino ADK board or Arduino + USB Host Shield, then you can get the latest libraries from https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0

Comment: ,thanks for the reply.Two more questions.
1.there is no other app in my phone which uses the accessory.
2.In arduino serial prints I see logs that say  disconnect then connect again...this happens two three time before the connection becomes stable.
I will try using the USB host shield from the above link,

Comment: Are you getting the same problem even in different cables?

Comment: @sundar, ye still getting error..I have ADk2011 board.does that make any differnce?